# convert hive table to .sql insert

Tags: sql, csv, hive, dump

Want to convert the hive table into SQL insert dump so I can use it in my local MySQL DB, table contains more than 30 million records try to achieve that by importing CSV but not succeeded because of CSV record limits, etc.

Comment: A CSV file is generally a better way to transfer the data.

Comment: i know but for my usecase i need .sql archive that contain all the data. do you know any way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with it using [dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io/).

Export a table (right click on table -> Export data) or resultset (right click -> Export results). Then choose "Export to SQL INSERT statements" format

[image]

But, imho, csv/tsv is better way...